# Delta in Covered Calls?

Tags: greeks, delta

Just want to check whether i understand it correctly:

Long Calls have positive delta

Long Puts have negative Delta

Long stock has 0.01 delta

100 Shares have 1 delta

Therefore:
Covered Call = 1 minus delta of Call option.

Is this correct?

Comment: Essentially yes, but I would go with a 1 delta for each stock and if the option is written on 100 underlying shares then you adjust accordingly. Most options, taking all markets into account, are not written on 100 units of underlying.

Comment: yes, think of a buy/write as a short put (they're the same thing except for stock rate risks)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.theoptionsguide.com/in-the-money-covered-calls.aspx

Look at the chart on this site. Do you see how the line is upward sloping for a covered call until the stock reaches a price of 45? To simplify things, you have a delta of 1 until 45 and then a delta of 0 after 45 onwards. Delta is the slope of the line. Delta of a covered call changes depending on how ITM your short call.